# MySql Get voters who voted the same

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables:

## Users

```
record_id   first_name   last_name
1           John         Smith
2           Jim          Brown
3           Jane         Goodall
```

### Polls

```
record_id   poll_question
1           What is your age?
2           What is your occupation?
```

### Poll Options

```
record_id   poll_id  option_text
1           1        16-20
2           1        21-25
3           2        builder
4           2        technician
```

### Poll Votes

```
record_id   user_id   poll_id   option_id
1           1         1         1
2           1         2         1
3           2         1         2
4           2         2         1
```

Given a specified user, how do I get all OTHER users who selected the same options for the polls answered by the specified user.

Ideally, it would provide a descending list of users according to how many questions were answered the same, i.e. users who voted all exactly the same would be at the top, down to users with no answers in common.

Comment: In your "Poll Votes" table you have fields poll_id and option_id. Record with record_id 4 has poll_id 2 and option_id 1. It is not obvious which record from table "Poll Options" is represented by those ids since record_id 1 has poll_id 1. It would be better if you ommit poll_id column from "Poll Votes" table and let option_id column be the key to "Poll Options" record_id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, v.Answers
FROM Users AS u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT pv.user_id AS user, COUNT(*) AS Answers
    FROM PollVotes AS pv
    WHERE ((poll_id, option_id) IN
        (
            SELECT poll_id, option_id
            FROM PollVotes
            WHERE user_id = YOURUSER
        ))
    AND pv.user_id != YOURUSER
    GROUP BY pv.user_id
    ) AS v
ON u.record_id = v.user
WHERE u.record_id != YOURUSER
ORDER BY v.Answers DESC
```

The inner query selects all users with the same `(poll_id, option_id)` combination as the selected user. The rowcount per user is the number of common answers. The left join with the user table is to include users with no common answers in the result.

Comment: Thanks pinouchon! Thought about it in the inner query, but missed it in the left join.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
SELECT u1.record_id, u1.first_name, u1.last_name, u2.record_id comp_record_id, u2.first_name comp_first_name, u2.last_name comp_last_name, u1.options FROM (
    SELECT u.record_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, GROUP_CONCAT(pv.poll_id,'.', pv.option_id ORDER BY pv.poll_id, pv.option_id) options
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN poll_votes pv ON pv.user_id = u.record_id
    GROUP BY u.record_id
) u1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT u.record_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, GROUP_CONCAT(pv.poll_id,'.', pv.option_id ORDER BY pv.poll_id, pv.option_id) options
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN poll_votes pv ON pv.user_id = u.record_id
    GROUP BY u.record_id
) u2 ON u1.options = u2.options AND u1.record_id <> u2.record_id 
WHERE u1.record_id = 1;
```

The two inner queries are identical, and could actually be turned into a view. The outer query simply joins the two on the question / answer lists to get the matches.